# Oracle SQL - trace database

Tags: sql, oracle, trace

I am coming from a microsoft SQL world so I am familiar with using SQL server profiler and sp_whoisactive. I am now in a scenario where I am working with an application with an oracle DBMS.

I want to be able to turn a trace on, go and click through the application and then stop trace and see what is happening at the database level. i.e. what SQL executes

From searching I can see I can use the session browser in TOAD - but I am getting an error (SYS.DBMS_SYSTEM must be declared). I know I can fix this accordnig to http://technopark02.blogspot.com/2012/03/resolving-pls-00201-identifier.html

But I dont want to make these changes to the system.

Is there a way I can run something like this query to run recursively ( found on stack exchange) and get it to write to a temporary table or file.

```
    SELECT sess.sid,
       sess.username,
       sqla.optimizer_mode,
       sqla.hash_value,
       sqla.address,
       sqla.cpu_time,
       sqla.elapsed_time,
       sqla.sql_text
    FROM v$sqlarea sqla, v$session sess
    WHERE sess.sql_hash_value = sqla.hash_value
    AND sess.sql_address = sqla.address
   AND sess.SID = 'SESSIONID'
```

In summery I would like to be able to run a trace without having to make changes to the system. maybe something like sp_whoisactive (by adam mechanic for SQL Server) writing to a file or table etc.

Anyone have any ideas

Comment: You want a trace? Because? Maybe your aprouch isn't correct. What's the problem your trying to solve? When you want to capture EVERY sql a session is executing this would not help you for sure! You need more rights to enable a trace for someone-else-s session. It is possible but it would generated a realy large trace file which is not readable for the first time reader or the faint-of-heart.

Comment: For session tracing (as @hetOrakel says though, potentially dumps a lot of details): https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof

Comment: For profiling: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler or  https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-hierarchical-profiler-11gr1

Comment: What do you mean "run recursively"?